# Turning 2 arrays into a two-dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I am trying to take two arrays and turn them into one 2 dimensional array. However, I keep getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at test5.sum(test5.java:12)
 at test5.main(test5.java:38)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class test5 {
    int[][] final23;

    public int[][] sum(int[] x, int[] y) {
        final23 = new int[2][x.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < final23[i].length; i++) {

            final23[1][i] = x[i];
            final23[2][i] = y[i];
        }
        return final23;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < final23[i].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < final23[i].length; j++) {

                System.out.print(final23[i][j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int l[] = { 7, 7, 3 };
        int k[] = { 4, 6, 2 };
        test5 X = new test5();

        X.sum(k, l);
        X.print();
    }
}
```

I am not really sure what the problem is. Sorry if the question is dumb, I am new to coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a second problem with your program. You have this loop in both `sum` and `print` methods:

```
for (int i = 0; i < final23[i].length; i++)
```

In sum method it should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < final23[0].length; i++)
```

And in print method

```
for (int i = 0; i < final23.length; i++)
```

Otherwise you'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` again.

Note that the program works correctly only if both input arrays have the same length. This might be ok for your purposes, but keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is:

```
final23 [2][i] = y[i];
```

Java arrays always start at 0. So final23 only has [0] and [1].

Any array with *n* elements can go from 0 to *n*-1.

Comment: As well as arrays in most of the common programming languages. At least in those derived from C.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i < final23[i].length; i++)
 {

  final23 [0][i] = x[i];
  final23 [1][i] = y[i];
 }
```

Remember, all arrays are 0 based, even n-dimensional ones.